# Wordpress local server to web database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, local

I'm installing wordpress and I'd like to use a web mysql database rather than a local one. Is this possible? I used the same exact credentials for an already existing web wordpress installation with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your web server allows remote MySQL connections, then yes. Just set your `DB_HOST` in **wp-config.php** correctly.